# Lodash - Merge array of nested objects based on parent key

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array of array nested objects (however, there could be more objects in it!):

```
[
  {
    foo: { something: [{}] },
    bar: { something: [{}] },
    etc: { something: [{}] },
    ...
  },
  {
    foo: { something: [{}] },
    bar: { something: [{}] },
    etc: { something: [{}] },
    ...
  },
];
```

I want to merge them by the key of each object with Lodash, so "foo" goes with "foo" and so on. What is inside `something` should be merged too.

The result should be:

```
  {
    foo: { something: [{}, {}] },
    bar: { something: [{}, {}] },
    etc: { something: [{}, {}] },
  },
```

There can be duplicates inside `something`, so I'm guessing `uniqBy` does not work here. Because the keys are nested inside the array, I feel a bit unsure of whether this needs `merge` or `assign` or another method, but since it should be done by dynamic keys, I haven't been able to make this work. I have looked at several similar questions, but no case has fit my scenario.

I have attempted

```
// does not do anything other than give "undefined" to the key of each object
groupBy(array, (group, key) => group[key])

// I don't know what to use for the iteratee argument, so this just returns undefined
groupBy(map(array, (group, key) => group[key]))
```

Comment: What is the rule for de-duplicating objects inside the `something` array? Does key order matter?

Comment: have you made an attempt? can you share [mcve]?

Comment: @AndrewParks order does not matter.

Comment: Can objects inside the something array contain property values that are arrays or objects?

Comment: @AndrewParks The "something" is an array of objects, but objects inside have no more levels, they have simple properties with a simple object being the most complex structure inside

Comment: Does each top-level object always contain all of the keys (foo, bar, ....), even if the something array is empty?

Comment: Yes, I think that is safe to assume

Comment: Lodash won’t give you anything here that isn’t already available in ES6. Consider weaning yourself from that toolkit, it’s largely redundant these days compared to native code.

Comment: @DanielBeck No JavaScript library gives you anything not available in JavaScript.

Comment: @DanielBeck It does make the code much more compact and more readable, in my opinion

Comment: @Unmitigated when lodash and underscore were first created they included a lot of helpful utilities that weren't otherwise readily available at the time.  Now most of those utilities are just built in parts of regular old javascript; there really isn't any reason to use lodash other than being used to its syntax.  (I'll admit this is a bit of a hobbyhorse of mine, I've been on a crusade to strip lodash out of our codebase because it's a persistent source of security issues; so far we've found exactly  zero cases where it's still doing something we can't trivially translate into ES6.)

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes the objects within the something arrays, sorts them into consistent key order, and uses a Map() to deduplicate the objects by the JSON representation of the consistent-key-order objects.

```js
const data = [
  {
    foo: { something: [{a:1}] },
    bar: { something: [{b:1, c:9}] },
    etc: { something: [{}] },
  },
  {
    foo: { something: [{a:2}] },
    bar: { something: [{c:9, b:1}] },
    etc: { something: [{}] },
  }
];

function dedup(arr) {
  return [...new Map(
      arr.map(i=>[JSON.stringify(Object.entries(i)
          .sort(([a],[b])=>a.localeCompare(b))),i])
    ).values()] 
}

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(data[0])
  .map(k=>[k, dedup(data.flatMap(i=>i[k].something))])))
```

Comment: Thank you. Why are you using a sort?

Comment: @Doge it is sorting object keys, so that `{c: 1, b:1}` will become `{b: 1, c:1}` before comparing it with another object that is `{b: 1, c:2}` for de-duplication purposes. I've updated the answer with an example of this